# removeSelf() a nil value error

Tags: lua, coronasdk

Hi for some reason corona is giving me this error: attempt to index global 'backC' (a nil value)

```
local randomBackC = function()
    backC = display.newImage("Cloud"..tostring(math.random(1, 4))..".png")
    backC.x = math.random (30, 450); backC.y = -20
    physics.addBody( backC, { density=2.9, friction=0.5, bounce=0.7, radius=24 } )
end
timer.performWithDelay( 500, randomBackC, 0 )
end
local function cleanup()
   if backC.y >100 then
       backC:removeSelf()
     end
end
Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", cleanup)
```

any ideas of what is causing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**backC** may be already removed because of the **Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", cleanup)**

**enterFrame** will call the cleanup() over and over again, so you have to remove the **enterFrame** after you remove the **backC** and if you want to create multiple objects, make it local only to the function because it may cause referencing problem.

Like this

```
local randomBackC = function()
    local backC = display.newImage("Cloud"..tostring(math.random(1, 4))..".png")
    backC.x = math.random (30, 450); backC.y = -20
    physics.addBody( backC, { density=2.9, friction=0.5, bounce=0.7, radius=24 } )

    local cleanup
    cleanup = function()
       if backC then
           if backC.y >100 then
               backC:removeSelf()
               backC = nil
               Runtime:removeEventListener("enterFrame", cleanup)
           end
       end
    end
    Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", cleanup)
end
timer.performWithDelay( 500, randomBackC, 0 )
```